# FileUpload Status Indicator ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, status

There are other similar posts, but they all want a progress bar. I don't care.

I will probably end up buying Ajax Uploader, but I would like to know if there is a way to just let the user know if a file is in the process of being uploaded.  I have tried an Ajax ProgressIndicator but it doesn't work...The file upload part works, but the progresscontent does not get displayed.

Here is what I have without the Ajax:

```
<asp:FileUpload onchange="clickTheButton();" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ForeColor="#ffffff" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="#ffffff" BorderWidth="0"
                ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Image" OnClick="AddImage_Click" />
```

Just a file upload control and a button that uploads the file.

**All I need is a way to let the user know that it is busy sending the file.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just create some hidden element on the page like this:

```
<div id="loadingDiv" style="display: none;">Please wait, uploading file...</div>
```

and then in the OnClientClick of your upload button, return a function like so:

```
function displayWaitingMessage(){
    document.getElementById('loadingDiv').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
}
```

Should display the message and then proceed with the postback to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just query your server at reasonable intervals with Ajax to see if the file you're trying to upload exists yet, and show an appropriate indication based on the response.

Comment: This is more of a 1-5 second operation.  I don't think this approach makes sense.  I just want the user to know something is happening.  As soon as the file is uploaded it appears in a datalist.  I just need something to say Uploading... between the time they click and the time the DataList is repopulated.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're asking for then. Just attach a Javascript event to the form button. When its clicked, hide the upload control and show an element that indicates that the upload is in progress.

Comment: Good point.  I've been up too long.

Ended up using Uploadify.  Does multiple files and its easy.  Although I think I am going to write an article on how to use it in ASP.Net, because there isn't an article making each step clear.  I'll post a link if I get around to writing it.

Comment: That would be awesome - please do!